# Best practice to use retrofit with a big json response

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to make calls to my API, but the data is to big, and I only want to start another activity if the call is complete, the way I'm doing it the screen freezes until the request is complete and the other activity start, is there a better way to do it?

```
 Call<List<Pessoa>> callPessoa = apiService.getClientes(GlobalModel.getToken(), GlobalModel.geEmpresaId());
                Call<List<Transportadora>> callTransportadora = apiService.getTransportadoras(GlobalModel.getToken(), GlobalModel.geEmpresaId());
  callPessoa.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pessoa>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Pessoa>> call, Response<List<Pessoa>> response) {
                        int statuscode = response.code();
                        if (statuscode == 200) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                                Pessoa mPessoa = response.body().get(i);
                                mRepositorio.addCliente(mPessoa.getPessoa_id(), mPessoa.getPessoa_nome(), mPessoa.getPessoa_nome_fantasia(), mPessoa.getPessoa_documento(), mPessoa.getPessoa_documento_tipo(), mPessoa.getEmpresa_id(), mPessoa.getPessoa_perfil());
                            }



                            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavigationMain.class);
                            startActivity(mIntent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            btnAutenticar.setText("ENTRAR");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Pessoa>> call, Throwable t) {
                        if (t.getMessage() != null) {
                            Log.v(TAG, t.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                });

callTransportadora.enqueue(new Callback<List<Transportadora>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Transportadora>> call, Response<List<Transportadora>> response) {
                        int statuscode = response.code();
                        if (statuscode == 200) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {

                                Transportadora mTransportadora = response.body().get(i);
                                mRepositorio.addTransportadora(mTransportadora.getPessoa_id(), mTransportadora.getPessoa_nome(), mTransportadora.getPessoa_nome_fantasia(), mTransportadora.getPessoa_documento(), mTransportadora.getPessoa_documento_tipo(), mTransportadora.getEmpresa_id(), mTransportadora.getPessoa_perfil());

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Transportadora>> call, Throwable t) {
                        if (t.getMessage() != null) {
                            Log.v(TAG, t.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Comment: consider using asynctask